# truffle migrate fails silently

Tags: solidity, truffle, infura, hd-wallets

I'm trying to deploy a truffle project to testnet. When I run `truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby  --verbose-rpc`, this is output:

```
You can improve web3's peformance when running Node.js versions older than 10.5.0 by installing the (deprecated) scrypt package in your project
You can improve web3's peformance when running Node.js versions older than 10.5.0 by installing the (deprecated) scrypt package in your project

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/StarNotary.sol
...
> Artifacts written to /home/how/projects/_mooc/blockchain/starNotary_3/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang
```

It doesn't create any contract neither in testnet nor locally, and it doesn't mention what goes wrong.

Here is relevant content of `truffle.js` file:

```js
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 9545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    rinkeby: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNENOMIC, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY),
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 3000000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000
    }
  }
}
```

I tried pinging rinkeby.infura.io and it doesn't seem to respond. Can it be that I just can't reach the network?

---

edit #01

### Scripts in `migrations` folder

```js
// 1_initial_migration.js
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

```js
// 2_deploy_contracts.js
const StarNotary = artifacts.require("StarNotary");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(StarNotary, "Udacity Star Token", "UST");
};
```

### Link to project

https://github.com/SteveRedka/Star_Notary

Comment: What version of truffle are you using? Are your mnemonic and infura key valid? Try deleting build/ then compile and migrate. Whats scripts do you have in the migration folder?

Comment: Truffle 5.0.32. Yes, both keys are valid, and if they weren't, valid why wouldn't it raise an error?
After deleting build nothing changes: it still deploys locally and fails to deploy to network.

Comment: Added scripts into question, as well as link to project

Answer (score 2):

I've just cloned your repo, entered my mnemonic and infura_api_key to .env and everything was ok, I ran `truffle migrate --network rinkeby` and the contract deployed successfully.

Try re-installing dependencies and `truffle`. May be you do not use `''` when adding mnemonic and api key to the `.env`. Also, my settings in Infura are all the default, you may have restricted access to your api key. My truffle version is `v5.0.33`.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect to an other blockchain provider like your local node if it works then it's a problem related to infura .. also you can hardcode the project id in the url just to be sure that it's the right one